# Does there exist a power of 2 which is the concatenation of two powers of 2?

Tags: number-theory, recreational-mathematics

I am curious whether there exists a power of $2$,

$z = d_1d_2\ldots d_n$ (where $d_i$ is the $i$-th digit of $z$), such that $z_1 = d_1d_2\ldots d_j$ and $z_2 = d_{j+1}d_{j+2}\ldots d_n$, $1\le j\le n$, are both powers of 2.

For example, imagine 56 was a power of 2, then $2^8 = 256$ would be an example of such a $z$, because 256 can be split up as 2|56, where 2 and 56 are powers of 2. Of course, 56 is not an actual power of 2, so 256 is not really an example of such a z.

I have checked all powers of 2 up to those with 1000 digits, but I can't think how to prove or disprove the existence of $z$.

(This is not a homework assignment or anything, I'm just curious).

Comment: I suspect you can work this out for yourself if you just write down what it means (using base ten for "concatenation").  As a warm-up exercise, would it be possible in base two?  The argument is less obvious in base ten, but actually not more difficult once you figure out how to express a power of two as the base ten concatenation of two such powers.

Comment: It's perhaps worth nothing that there are triple-concatenations, such as $128$ and (if you allow intervening zeroes) $1024$ and $2048$. I think there was a question here about such things some time ago.

Comment: I may have misunderstood your example, but based on the example of 256, then it seems like 24, 28, 216, 232,264, 2128, 2256, 2512, 21024, etc... all qualify

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From
$$2^r\cdot10^k+2^s=2^t$$
we get
$$2^{r-s}\cdot 10^k+1=2^{t-s}$$

Since $s$ is clearly lesser than  $t$, LHS must be even, so $r-s+k=0$ or $s=r+k$. Now,
$$2^r\cdot10^k+2^{r+k}=2^t$$ 
or
$$2^k(5^k+1)=2^{t-r}$$
This implies that $5^k+1$ is a power of $2$, but $5^k+1\equiv 1+1\equiv 2\pmod 4$, so $k=0$. But if $k=0$, there's no "concatenation", in the sense you mean.

I have used critically the fact that we usually write numbers in base $10$, so the question remains open for other bases.

Comment: I really like your approach, but I'm not sure I see why $r - s + k = 0$. Unless both $r - s$ and $k$ need to be 0, in which case I agree.

Comment: @pjs36 $2^{r-s}10^k$ must be odd, but still an integer. Since this is $2^{r-s+k}5^k$, then $r-s+k=0$.

Comment: While clearly $r,s \lt t$, I think the cases $r \ge s$ and $r \lt s$ have to be considered separately.

Comment: @hardmath I suspect it's actually not too hard to show that $r\gt s$ - this is a consequence of the fact that the length of the period of $2^m\bmod 10^n$ is 'sufficiently long'; in this case, it only has to be larger than $\approx 3n$, which should be easily provable (**EDIT** and is: see http://www.exploringbinary.com/cycle-length-of-powers-of-two-mod-powers-of-ten/ )

Answer (score 1):

If there were such an example, then you would have two numbers $x,y$ such that $x$ and $y$ are both powers of $2$ and yet $z = 10^n x + y$ is also a power of two for some $n$. Let $2^k = y$. If $n > k$ Then $z/y = 5^n 2^{n-k}x + 1$, which is odd since $n > k$. Thus $z/y$ is not a power of two so $z$ cannot be a power of two. I'm not sure what happens when $n \leq k$.